# Preserve text line breaks to when collecting from database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, replace, preserve

I'm very new to programming and are trying hard to learn. I've been struggling with an issue for a few hours without understanding what I'm doing wrong.

My goal is to save text (article with a lot of line breaks) to a database, and then retrieve the text and view the output as it was written, with all line breaks preserved.

The text is part of an object named KaseriInfo.

I've read some topics regarding this and tried the following:

Before saving to the Db I use the `inputText.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");`
After retrieving from Db I user the `inputText.Replace("<br />", "\r\n");`

I've been mixing with the .Replace-methods in different ways but I won't get the result I wish for.

This is my code for adding to the database using a local web service:

```
public bool AddKaseri(KaserierInfo kaseri)
    {
        bool successOrNot = false;
        Kaserier kaseriToBeAdded = new Kaserier();
        kaseriToBeAdded.Title = kaseri.Title;
        kaseriToBeAdded.Content = kaseri.Content.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
        kaseriToBeAdded.About = kaseri.About;
        kaseriToBeAdded.Uploaded = DateTime.Now;

        db.Kaseriers.Add(kaseriToBeAdded);
        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
            successOrNot = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        return successOrNot;
    }
```

And this is the code for retrieving the data from the Db:

```
public KaserierInfo GetOneKaseri(int id)
    {
        var result = from row in db.Kaseriers
                     where row.Id == id
                     select row;

            KaserierInfo kaseri = new KaserierInfo();

        var kas = result.FirstOrDefault();
        if (kas != null)
        {
            kaseri.Id = kas.Id;
            kaseri.Title = kas.Title;
            kaseri.About = kas.About;
            kaseri.Content = kas.Content.Replace("<br />", "\r\n");
            kaseri.UploadedDateOnly = kas.Uploaded.ToString();
            kaseri.Uploaded = kas.Uploaded;
            kaseri.UploadedDateOnly = kaseri.Uploaded.ToLongDateString();
        }
        return kaseri;
    }
```

[What is stored in the Db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHjSx.png)

The HTML-output won't come with line breaks for some reason. This is what is displayed:

[Output on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv6iZ.png)

Here is the C# code inside the controller responsible:

```
 public ActionResult ViewKaseri(int id)
    {
        //Getting the object from WS
        var kas = kasref.GetOneKaseri(id);
        //Moving to local object
        KaseriModel kaseri = new KaseriModel();
        kaseri.Id = kas.Id;
        kaseri.About = kas.About;
        kaseri.Title = kas.Title;
        kaseri.Content = kas.Content;
        kaseri.UploadedDateOnly = kas.UploadedDateOnly;        
        return View(kaseri);
    }
```

I would be glad to solve this so that the line breaks will be rendered correctly. Please keep in mind that my skills are low.

Best
/J

Comment: Post the code you use to inject the data into your HTML page. You could also post the resulting markup...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use @Html.Raw(). This will allow you to display the contents

Comment: Thanks. There is probably some other thing that is causing the problem. I tried with @Html.Rav(Model.Content) but the output looks the same unfortunately.

Comment: did you wrapped it around <pre> tag ?

Comment: Eventually I got it to work using @Html.Rav(). Thanks!